# RecyclerView smoothscroll doesn't work with many items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create list message like periscope chat. That mean it look like new message slide up and it is moving other items. I am using smooth scroll when i have more than 5 message. All looks fine but after couple of message smooth scroll doesn't work.

I overrided `smoothScrollToPostion()` method

```
@Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state,
                                       int position) {
        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {
            @Override
            public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                return ResizableLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
            }

            @Override
            protected int calculateTimeForScrolling(int dx) {
                // Value of dx is 0 when is lot of message
                return 100;
            }

        };

        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
```

Class `ResizableLayoutManager` extended `LinearLayoutManager`

Comment: Why do you want to use List view for pericope chat animation? You can inflate linear layout add it to main layout and remove after some time .

Comment: yes. It is good idea. But My list is scrolling by user. Each view is reused. If I set animation for some view then this animation could be resued. I found solution with handler and it works properly